# ElasticSearch as a Relational Database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am using MongoDb and want my NodeJs application to have both the Full and partial text search capabilities. Is is good idea to have Elasticsearch as a Search Engine and Relational Database ?, Because i want my application to have single source of data store.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch is not built for relation database usage. It is basically a DB for textual search.

I have used ES successfully to search my documents based on textual data and then search the id/key of that document in relation database to extract detailed information.

Comment: But my search depends on relational data . what to do?

Comment: for example i may be searching videos of Users who are in my friend list